# Intel TSX programming environement

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, intel, transactional-memory, intel-tsx

I have an intel Xeon CPU E3-1245 v5 machine supporting Intel TSX technology (checked using https://github.com/andikleen/tsx-tools/blob/master/has-tsx.c).
I tried to run the following RTM code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

int main()
{
   unsigned status = _xbegin();
   if ((status == _XBEGIN_STARTED) {
       printf("%d", _xtest());
       _xend();
    } else printf("Transaction failed");
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles without errors, but I got a "Segmentation Fault" error on _xend() instruction at runtime.
Please, can anyone tell me how to setup a proper environment to write, compile and run TSX RTM programs?

Comment: On my Skylake-client desktop, I get "Transaction failed".  (After fixing the syntax error, too many opening `(` in the `if`.)  I also had to compile with ` -mrtm` on top of `gcc -O3 -march=native`; it seems GCC12.2 `-march=native` knows that RTM is disabled by the Linux kernel on my system.  (Despite booting with `tsx=on tsx_async_abort=off`)  Or else GCC `-march=native` doesn't look for RTM.

Comment: Anyway, you certainly shouldn't expect `printf` to succeed inside a transaction, even if you omit a newline so it's just appending to a buffer.  IDK why you'd get a segfault, though.  A fixed version of the code on Godbolt compiles and runs (https://godbolt.org/z/53h3z9fsT with gcc12.1 `-march=native`, not 12.2), showing `_xtest()` returned 0 or aborted inside the attempted transaction, with the printf moved outside.

Comment: My system reports "RTM: No" from that old 2013 CPUID detection, as expected.  (i7-6700k with updated microcode, Arch Linux 6.2.7-arch1-1).  What did you do to get it to report "yes"?  I still wouldn't expect a segfault; if something causes a transaction abort inside printf, it should all get rolled back.